# Differential equation using differential operator method

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$
y"-2y'+y=x\sin x\\
(D^2-2D+1)y= x\sin x\\
y= \frac{x \sin x}{(D^2-2D+1)} \\
\mathrm{Im} { {\frac{x e^{ix}}{(D+i)^2-2(D+i)+1}}}= \mathrm{Im}{\frac{x  e^{ix}}{D^2+2(i-1)D-2i}} = \\
=\mathrm{Im}\left({\frac{-x}{2i}- \frac{1+i}{2i}e^{ix}}\right).
$$

I'm stuck, can someone give me hint how can I change the complex number
$ \mathrm{Im}{\frac{x  e^{ix}}{D^2+2(i-1)D-2i}}$  to $\mathrm{Im}\left({\frac{-x}{2i}- \frac{1+i}{2i}e^{ix}}\right)$?

And for this problem do you prefer using variation of parameter / undetermined coefficient / differential operator method? I tried using variation of parameter, the integral is so messy.

Thank you!

Comment: $\mathrm{Im}{\frac{x  e^{ix}}{D^2+2(i-1)D-2i}}$ is not a complex number. It's an operator.